# What's a good pattern or style in REST Resource classes to encapsulate error handling?

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I've run into this pattern several times. In pseudo-code:

`public class BlahResource {
  if (thisError)
    buildResponse(BAD_REQUEST);
  if (thatError)
    buildResponse(CONFLICT);
  ...
  doSomething();
  return buildResponse(SUCCESS);
}`

Doesn't look too bad, but when you have a million error conditions to handle, too much business logic accretes into the Resource class and the noise quickly overwhelms the story of what the code is actually *doing*.

Since in a resource the error conditions are returning something, an exception thrown from a service doesn't seem right to me. And a status object encapsulating different combinations of return conditions and setups seems like overkill.

Is there something obvious I'm missing in how this can be coded in a logical, clear way? Possibly something functional/Guava/lambda-based that I'm missing, or just a regular OO solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete [JSR-349 Bean Validation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr349/index.html) specification addressing these concerns

From the **specification goals**

> Validating data is a common task that occurs throughout an
>   application, from the presentation layer to the persistence layer.
>   Often the same validation logic is implemented in each layer, proving
>   to be time consuming and errorprone. To avoid duplication of these
>   validations in each layer, developers often bundle validation logic
>   directly into the domain model, **cluttering domain classes with
>   validation code that is, in fact, metadata about the class itself**.
>   This JSR defines a metadata model and API for JavaBean validation. The
>   default metadata source is annotations, with the ability to override
>   and extend the meta-data through the use of XML validation
>   descriptors.

The [hibernate-validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-gettingstarted.html) is the reference implementation, but just note that the implementation is not tied to any tier (nor web nor the persistence tier)

Going back to your resource code, this would mean that, by utilizing the custom constraints, your Resource would look something like

```
public class BlahResource {
  @CheckBadRequest
  @CheckConflict
  private field
  ...
}
```

when the validation fails, the errors are stored inside [ConstraintViolation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) that you can obtain through [Validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) interface. Those are the central points around which you should build your error handling mechanism, again a pseudo

```
Set<Constraintviolation<Resource>> violations = validator.validate(Resource);
```

Comment: I'm working on getting Jersey bean validation up in my project, this would take care of some of the clutter. My main problem is business logic validation (this case with this case requires this configuration value), and database validation against the existence of certain parameters. Does the validation you're describing go beyond simple numeric/not null/check constraints? I don't see it in a quick scan of the doc you linked.

Comment: my point with the post was that you should have your validation logic as a meta-data to your class to avoid clutter, and used hibernate-validator as an example. But it even more relevent since you use Jersey, since Jersey's bean validation is based on hibernate validator, so its a good thing.  To answer you question, yes, you can make more complex business validation, here's an old post validating if the user exist in DB http://reyjexter.blogspot.it/2008/02/custom-hibernate-validator-that.html